# "Could not load file or assembly" while assembly is definitely found. Trying to use a custom assembly in T4 template

Tags: c#, .net, bind, .net-assembly, t4

Note: I've read all related SO (and google) Q/A neither solved this scenario, please read before link/mark as duplicate. I am doing exactly (originally) what all solutions describe + there are a many (strange) diagnostics.

I would like to use my custom class library from a T4 template. It seems there is a binding error, but I can not figure out what is it.

The line in my .tt template file:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)..\..\output\debug\net45\ComiCalc.Data\ComiCalc.Data.dll" #>
```

Diagnostics info and what I've tried so far:

**EDIT made here and added point 1: If I copy...:**

1. If I copy my custom assembly to one of the C:\ based paths shown in the error exhibit #1's log, then all works. However this is not a solution because: a) After the first generation this file is locked by the IDE, so I can not modify my custom assembly source, because when building it the build process can not overwrite. b) I suppose this is not the way it supposed to work, the absolute path should work)
2. If I intentionally change the path/file name to a wrong one (like ComiCalc.Data.XXX.dll) I got slightly different error message, *with no version info*.
3. Please examine the the error message: there is version info. This could not go from anywhere else just from directly from my assembly metainfo, so this assembly *was definitely found*
4. I am monitoring the generation process with SysInternals (MS) ProcessMonitor. There are some successful open/read operation on D:...ComiCalc.Data.dll during the generation process. With the intentionally changed *wrong* file name the same access results PATH NOT FOUND in ProcessMonitor.
5. I set the binding logging enabled, so we have a log at the end of the exception instead of the WRN. (see th 1st error exhibit). Interestingly this log does not show any D:\ related binding error instead talks about C:\ related problems. The path I am giving (and found) in the directive is a full D:\ path.
6. FusLogVw shows only one error during IDE load, (not during code generation) (see the 2nd error exhibit below)
7. The custom assembly references only standard GAC assemblies + Microsoft.CSharp what I set copy local: true, so all references should be available to load either from the GAC either in the very same folder where my custom assembly located.
8. I am using VS 2015, but I do not think this matters, just saying. I can recall similar scenario in VS 2013, just leaved it unresolved.
9. I've restarted everything including my iPad, nothing helped.

I am hopeless now.

Error message in the IDE error pane, when saving the .tt template and triggering the code generation process:

```
Severity Code    Description Project File Line
Error Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ComiCalc.Data, Version=1.2015.4.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'ComiCalc.Data, Version=1.2015.4.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at[0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at ComiCalc.Data.EF6Utility.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(Object textTransformation) in D:\2014Develop\.vsonline\ComiCalc\src\ComiCalc.Data\CodeGeneratorHelpers\EF6Utility\EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.cs:line 80
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6058F386C8C4C33267C623AA9201E1643E8BE690580268BB3C3A15857E3D865EDDDB9C9ACDE5595B31C038571AE207FD405066ABFC3DA8F47E4C6D2461ED80FB.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = ComiCalc.Data, Version=1.2015.4.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/ComiCalc.Data/ComiCalc.Data.EXE.   ComiCalc.Web    D:\2014Develop\.vsonline\ComiCalc\src\ComiCalc.Web\Generators\_MyEdmx\KendoGrid.tt  1
```

FusLogVw error (during ide load) **supposedly nothing to do with the issue**, just in case. This is the only error. Yes, I pressed the refresh button:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry(2015.08.12. @ 16:04:47) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002.The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = devenv.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms, Version= 4.0.0.0, Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/DiagnosticsHub/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms/System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: Using Assembly.Load, can you load it manually?

Comment: I am using the very same assembly in the very same location _with_ _no_ _errors_ by referencing to it in other project in the solution. Is this gives you the same diagnostics information?